# Convert datasource guid to string value in sitecore rendering

Tags: path, sitecore, datasource

In sitecore, when getting the datasource from the renderingcontext, it returns a guid.  Is there a means to convert this to the actual string value stored in the datasource field.
I want to run a "fast" query but need the path stored in the rendering context datasource instead of the guid.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If what you receive is a Guid, you can use

```
var idString = guid.ToString("B");
```

if what you receive is `Sitecore.Data.ID`, just use:

```
var idString = id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The guid that you are getting is the Sitecore ID of the datasource item. You should be able to get it's path directly:

```razor
var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource);
var dataSourcePath = dataSource.Paths.Path;
```

Comment: thanks.  This is what I was looking for.  I do have to evaluate the path so "#" can be wrapped around path nodes with spaces in them.  That's the next step.